# incorrect definition of bootstrap columns with kendo-ui inputs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui

I have a block of code

```
    <div class="form-row mt-3">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label for="beginDate">Start Date</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="beginDate">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label for="endDate">End Date</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="endDate">
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: without kendo]

Next im define Kendo datepicker to this inputs

```
$(function () {
    $("#beginDate").kendoDatePicker();
    $("#endDate").kendoDatePicker();
});
```

And result is:
[image: after kendo function]

I think col-6 don't work now.How i can fix this or i do smth wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully I have understood the problem but you are expecting the datepickers to be 100% width and not a pre-defined width.

Assuming that is the case here is a dojo I have prepared for you showing how to do this. 
https://dojo.telerik.com/osENoFAF

(I am assuming you are using bootstrap 4 in this example.)

All I have done is added a new/updated class for the `k-datepicker` kendo css class to set the width to 100%.

```
   <style>
    .k-datepicker{
    width:100%;
    }
  </style>
```